# What am I doing wrong? Using foreach loop to enter value field for <option>

Tags: php, mysql

This one is confusing me.  I have two different mySQL tables I need to pull information from and I am creating a html dropdown table and trying to populate the value from a variable.  It works the first time through the loop, but not after that.  I get a warning (when viewing the html):

```
b>Warning</b>:  array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in <b>/MY URL</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
<br />
```

Easier to just show the code, so here it is:

```
$UserID = "118";
$UndefinedEvents = array();
$EventDates = array();
$UserTimelines = array();


  $query = "SELECT * FROM  events  WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND ParentEventID IS NULL";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $query2 = "SELECT * FROM  timelines  WHERE UserID='$UserID'";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

  //Getting the Timeline names and their IDs
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    $UserTimelines[] = $row['TimeLineName'];
    $TimelineID[] = $row['TimeLineID'];
    }

  //Getting and events that have a NULL value   
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['UserID'] . " ".$row['EventName']. " " . $row['ParentEventID'];
    $UndefinedEvents[] = $row['EventName'];
    $EventDates[] = $row['StartDate'];
  }

  //Iterating through events with NULL value and telling user which events are NULL
  foreach (array_combine($UndefinedEvents, $EventDates) as $event=>$dates){
    echo "This Event does not have a Timeline associated with it: " .$event . " on ".$dates. '<br>';
  echo "Choose a Timeline:<br>";
  ?>

  <select>

  //THIS IS LINE 56:  Iterating through the timelines and creating a dropdown for the user to choose a timeline.
  <?php foreach (array_combine($TimelineID, $UserTimelines) as $TimelineID=>$timeline){ 
        echo "<option value=".$TimelineID."> ".$timeline. "</option>";

  }
  echo " </select><br><br>";
  }
  ?>

  <?php
    mysql_close($con);  
?>
```

Like I said, it works the first loop, and is properly putting the values in, but each loop after just creates the above warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second foreach, you are overwriting your `$TimelineID` variable:

```
foreach (array_combine($TimelineID, $UserTimelines) as $TimelineID=>$timeline){
```

Just use something else like:

```
foreach (array_combine($TimelineID, $UserTimelines) as $temp_TimelineID=>$timeline){
```

Comment: Ah!  Thanks!  I totally missed that.  I did realize that I also forgot to initialize the $TimelineID = array(); but it's strange because it doesn't seem to care???

Comment: @Joel It´s better to initialize it as an empty array, just in case there´s already something there...

Answer (score 0):

Just to check... in this code, you get the ID and name from one row, and put them into two separate arrays...

```
//Getting the Timeline names and their IDs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
    $UserTimelines[] = $row['TimeLineName'];
    $TimelineID[] = $row['TimeLineID'];
  }
```

...then you combine those arrays together later to generate the option value/description?

Why not store *both* values from each row in one element of an array (an array of arrays)? or use an associative array - with the id as the key, and the text as the value? (or better yet, map the rows to objects)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I guess at this point in my learning, I'm just happy to be building something that works. :) The above code as pretty much all that I need to achieve what I need to with this, so I don't see it as really saving me much work to do an associative array.

Comment: One phrase to research then is "technical debt". When you look at this code in six months, you'll be cursing yourself :-)